# Pydantic nested setting objects load env variables from file

Tags: python, pydantic

Using pydantic setting management, how can I load env variables on nested setting objects on a main settings class? In the code below, the `sub_field` env variable field doesn't get loaded. `field_one` and `field_two` load fine. How can I load an environment file so the values are propagated down to the nested `sub_settings` object?

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseSettings, Field


class SubSettings(BaseSettings):
    sub_field: Optional[str] = Field(None, env='SUB_FIELD')


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    field_one: Optional[str] = Field(None, env='FIELD_ONE')
    field_two: Optional[int] = Field(None, env='FIELD_TWO')
    sub_settings: SubSettings = SubSettings()


settings = Settings(_env_file='local.env')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some examples of nested loading of pydantic env variables in the [docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/settings/#parsing-environment-variable-values).

#### Option 1

If you're willing to adjust your variable names, one strategy is to use `env_nested_delimiter` to denote nested fields. This appears to be the way that pydantic expects nested settings to be loaded, so it should be preferred when possible.

So with a local.env like this:

```
FIELD_ONE=one
FIELD_TWO=2
SUB_SETTINGS__SUB_FIELD=value
```

You should be able to load the settings in this way

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseSettings


class SubSettings(BaseModel):
     # ^ Note that this inherits from BaseModel, not BaseSettings
    sub_field: Optional[str]


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    field_one: Optional[str]
    field_two: Optional[int]
    sub_settings: SubSettings

    class Config:
        env_nested_delimiter = '__'
```

#### Alternate

If you don't want to use the `env_nested_delimiter` functionality, you could load both sets of settings from the same `local.env` file. Then pass the loaded SubSettings to Settings directly. This can be done by overriding the `Settings` class `__init__` method

With this `local.env`

```
FIELD_ONE=one
FIELD_TWO=2
SUB_FIELD=value
```

use the following to load the settings

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseSettings, Field

class SubSettings(BaseSettings):
    sub_field: Optional[str]

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    field_one: Optional[str]
    field_two: Optional[int]
    sub_settings: SubSettings

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['sub_settings'] = SubSettings(_env_file=kwargs['_env_file'])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


settings = Settings(_env_file='local.env')
```

Comment: I removed the  explicit setting of the field's `env` option because the env option in your example matches the default behavior.

Comment: I should of clarfied, I want to do this without the nested delimiter, thanks though.

Comment: I just added an alternate solution. Maybe this is more along the lines of what you want?

Comment: yep that's exactly what I wanted, much appreciated.